# ETL job failing with pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException in AWS Glue

Tags: aws-glue

I have an ETL job in AWS glue that is triggered by a scheduler. My ETL language is python. 
I am trying to - Write the result of a query in an s3 bucket. For this, I have used sparkSql.
This job is failing when it is triggered by the scheduler but it succeeds when running it manually. It is throwing an error for a column (eventdate) which is available in spark df.

Below is the log.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_2018-06-22-11-10-05.py", line 48, in <module>
error_report_result_df = spark.sql(sql_query)
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529665635815_0001/container_1529665635815_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 603, in sql
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529665635815_0001/container_1529665635815_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529665635815_0001/container_1529665635815_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`eventdate`' given input columns: []; line 1 pos 480;1
```

Comment: Can you also paste your code? Is your code parametric? Are you passing same parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because of bookmark. I've have enabled the Job Bookmark [1] in my trigger definition. Please note that this is also the default choice when you create a Trigger. In this case, when the glueContext is called and it sees that there aren't new data to be processed, it returns an empty Dataframe (DF) and spark cannot infer any schema from it. This explains why the registered table on the DF does not have any field. The same doesn't apply if the script is launched by the Web Console because by default the Job Bookmark is disabled. When I disabled the bookmark, it worked.

[1] Job Bookmarks https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html

Comment: Bookmarks in Glue are the source of endless pain. One wonders why the dynamicframe wrapper would generate an empty collection, and then raise a very cryptic error when the Bookmark facility already has special knowledge that there is _no data to process_, it should just. no-op and log exactly that, "bookmark up to date, no data to process". Then I wouldn't have to spin up dev endpoint, try to debug in a sagemaker notebook, google for ages to find this (thankyou so helpful) question. I think I will stop using Bookmark and try storing batch state elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed, it makes sense to log the exact message

Comment: I discovered that this happened to me because my source table definition was ignoring the underlying partition directory structure, but I had then run MSCK repair table on it, which they created partition objects that conflicted with the table definition, and confused glue. For some reason Athena can query the tables just fine, but Glue is not clever enough. I solved it by dropping & recreating the table metadata (without partition objects).

Comment: You can do a check for new data with `df.rdd.isEmpty()` before processing